# Achieving a cross-fading image effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying build an image cross fade effect by

1. Putting the selected image on the front (position: -9999 to 0)
2. Putting the previous image on the back (position: 0 to -9999)
3. Increasing it's opacity until it reaches 1
4. Setting the opacity of the previous image to 0 (so I can repeat the proccess)

This is the code:

```
  <a-sky id="pano-1" src="image1" class="pano" opacity="0" position="-9999"></a-sky>
  <a-sky id="pano-2" src="image2" class="pano" opacity="0" position="-9999"></a-sky>

  var opacity = 0 // starting opacity
  var step = 0.1 // step size
  var target = 1 // target value
  var time = 50 // delay in milliseconds
  // start timer loop, and record it's index

  var increaseOpacity = setInterval(function () {
    // assuming your selector works, set opacity
    // increment opacity by step size
    opacity = (opacity * 10 + step * 10) / 10
    // if we reached our target value, stop the timer
    if (opacity > target) {
      clearInterval(increaseOpacity)
    }

  }, time)

  $(`#pano-${index}`).attr('position', 0)
  $('.pano').not(`#pano-${index}`).attr('position', -9999)
  $('.pano').not(`#pano-${index}`).attr('opacity', 0)
```

The images fade but without crossing each other (e.g. it goes old image > white > new image).

Maybe I have the order wrong? What to do to archive that effect?

Comment: what are those tags?

Comment: From here: https://aframe.io/docs/components/material.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are positioning the other elements before the fade completes. move them like so:-

```
  var opacity = 0 // starting opacity
  var step = 0.1 // step size
  var target = 1 // target value
  var time = 50 // delay in milliseconds
  // start timer loop, and record it's index

  var increaseOpacity = setInterval(function () {
    // assuming your selector works, set opacity
    // increment opacity by step size
    opacity = (opacity * 10 + step * 10) / 10
    // if we reached our target value, stop the timer
    if (opacity > target) {
      clearInterval(increaseOpacity)
      $('.pano').not(`#pano-${index}`).attr('position', -9999)
      $('.pano').not(`#pano-${index}`).attr('opacity', 0)
    }

  }, time)

  $(`#pano-${index}`).attr('position', 0)
```

The only other issue I could see now is a `z-index` one, but try this first.

Answer (score 1):

I think that tasks like these should be kept as simple as possible, 
for example, always use css where you can! Javascript should be used only for business logic.

```js
function SliderCtrl($) {
  var self = this;
  
  self.slider = $('#slider');
  self.imgs = $('img', self.slider);
  self.current = null;
  self.ACTIVE_CLASS = 'is-active';
  self.TIMING = 2000;
  
  self.changeSlide = function() {
    var current = $(self.current);
    var next = current.next().length ? current.next() : self.imgs.first();
    console.log(next, current)
    
        
    current.removeClass(self.ACTIVE_CLASS);
    next.addClass(self.ACTIVE_CLASS);
    self.current = next;
  };
  
  window.setInterval(self.changeSlide, self.TIMING);
  self.slider.removeClass('is-waiting');
}
$(document).ready(SliderCtrl);
```

```css
#slider {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  
  transition: 400ms all linear;
}

#slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  
  transition: 400ms all linear;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#slider img.is-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

#slider.is-waiting {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider" class="is-waiting">
  <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/53c46660e4b07557fac2eb85/t/550ee40ce4b02547ba9c325e/1427039245866/doug-rickard_a-new-american-picture_west-gallery-6-b1.jpg?format=1500w" />
  <img src="http://artandyou.ru/upload/mce/image/kerek/vs/portrait/doug-rickard_a-new-american-picture_east-gallery-6-b.jpg" />
  <img src="http://www.yossimilo.com/artists/chris-mccaw/images/full-chris_mccaw-marking_time-west_gallery-13.jpg" />
</div>
```